# Java 2D Game Tile Rendering Optimization

Tags: java, graphics, dictionary

I've been trying to make a 2D Tile-based game but didnt get very far before having some stuff go wrong.  The game is fine except for that it is extremely slow and spaces keep appearing between the tiles.  I tried putting all of the tile images into one image to load to make it smoother, but it didn't work.  I need help with how to optimize my game for better fps.

Most of Display Class

```
Player p = new Player();
static Map m = new Map();
Hotbar h = new Hotbar();
static Zombie z = new Zombie();

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Display());
    t1.start();
    Thread t2 = new Thread(z);
    t2.start();
    Thread t3 = new Thread(m);
    t3.start();
}

@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            oldTime = currentTime;
            currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            elapsedTime = currentTime - oldTime;
            fps = (int) ((1000 / 40) - elapsedTime);
            Thread.sleep(fps);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (started) {
            p.playerMovement();
            p.width = getWidth();
            p.height = getHeight();
            h.width = getWidth();
            h.height = getHeight();
            if (p.maptiles != null) {
                z.maptiles = new Rectangle[p.maptiles.length];
                z.maptiles = p.maptiles;
            }
        } else {

        }
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Most of Map Class

```
BufferedImage backLayer;
BufferedImage backLayer2;

@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
public void createBack() {
    backLayer = new BufferedImage(mapwidth * 32, mapheight * 32, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics g = backLayer.getGraphics();
    Graphics2D gd = (Graphics2D) g;
    Color daycolor = new Color(0, 150, 255, 255);
    Color nightcolor = new Color(0, 50, 100, Math.abs(time / daylength - 510 / 2));
    Color backtilecolor = new Color(10, 10, 20, Math.abs(time / daylength - 510 / 4));
    g.setColor(daycolor);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, p.width, p.height);
    g.setColor(nightcolor);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, p.width, p.height);
    time++;
    if (time > 510 * daylength)
        time = 0;
    if (time < 100 * daylength || time > 410 * daylength) {
        z.SpawnZombie();

    } else {

    }
    g.setColor(backtilecolor);
    int i = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < mapwidth; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < mapheight; y++) {
            if (mapdatasky[i] == 0) {
                p.mapsky[i] = new Rectangle(x * 32 - p.playerX, y * 32 - p.playerY, 32, 32);
            }
            if (mapdatasky[i] >= 1) {
                g.drawImage(tiles[mapdatasky[i]], x * 32 - p.playerX, y * 32 - p.playerY, 32, 32, null);
                mapsky[i] = new Rectangle(x * 32 - p.playerX, y * 32 - p.playerY, 32, 32);
                p.mapsky[i] = new Rectangle(x * 32 - p.playerX, y * 32 - p.playerY, 32, 32);
                gd.fill(mapsky[i]);
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    backLayer2 = backLayer;
}

BufferedImage middleLayer;
BufferedImage middleLayer2;

@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
public void createMiddle() {
    middleLayer = new BufferedImage(mapwidth * 32, mapheight * 32, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics g = middleLayer.getGraphics();
    Color fronttilecolor = new Color(20, 20, 40, Math.abs(time / daylength - 510 / 4));
    int i = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < mapwidth; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < mapheight; y++) {
            if (mapdata[i] == -1) {
                spawnX = x * 32 - p.width;
                spawnY = y * 32 - p.height;
                p.spawnX = spawnX;
                p.spawnY = spawnY;
            }
            if (mapdata[i] == 0) {
                p.mapsky[i] = new Rectangle(x * 32 - p.playerX, y * 32 - p.playerY, 32, 32);
            }
            if (mapdata[i] > 0) {
                g.drawImage(tiles[mapdata[i]], x * 32 - p.playerX, y * 32 - p.playerY, 32, 32, null);
                maptiles[i] = new Rectangle(x * 32 - p.playerX, y * 32 - p.playerY, 32, 32);
                p.maptiles[i] = new Rectangle(x * 32 - p.playerX, y * 32 - p.playerY, 32, 32);
            }
            if (!p.breaking) {
                tileid = -1;
            }
            if (tileid == i) {
                g.setColor(new Color(100, 0, 0, 100));
                g.fillRect(x * 32 - p.playerX + 16 - timer / (breaktime / 16), y * 32 - p.playerY + 16 - timer / (breaktime / 16), (timer / (breaktime / 16)) * 2, (timer / (breaktime / 16)) * 2);
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    g.setColor(fronttilecolor);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, p.width, p.height);
    middleLayer2 = middleLayer;
}


BufferedImage both;
BufferedImage both2;

public void mergeLayers() {
    both = new BufferedImage(mapwidth * 32, mapheight * 32, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics g = both.getGraphics();
    g.drawImage(backLayer2, 0, 0, mapwidth * 32, mapheight * 32, null);
    g.drawImage(middleLayer2, 0, 0, mapwidth * 32, mapheight * 32, null);
    both2 = both;
}

public void renderMap(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(both2, 0, 0, mapwidth * 32, mapheight * 32, null);
    if (placetimer > 0)
        placetimer--;
}
@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            oldTime = currentTime;
            currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            elapsedTime = currentTime - oldTime;
            fps = (int) ((1000 / 100) - elapsedTime);
            Thread.sleep(fps);
            if (!mapset) {
                setMap();
                mapset = true;
            }
            createBack();
            createMiddle();
            mergeLayers();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a picture of the rendering errors between tiles

Game Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This would be better suited for the Code Review site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that a review might be appropriate here.

But general hints: If you added this "merging" (createBack/createMiddle/mergeLayers) for performance reasons: Don't do it! There you are painting ALL tiles (and possibly also some that will not be visible anyhow, that could be clipped away when they are drawn directly with g.drawImage). Painting many small images into a large image, and then painting the large image on the screen, can hardly be faster than directly painting the small images on the screen in the first place....

If you added this "merging" to resolve the "stripes" that are appearing: Don't do it! The stripes come from the coordinates being changed from a different Thread than the one which is painting the images. You can avoid this by changing the way of how you compute the tiles and their coordinates. The code is slightly too ... "complex" to point it out, so I'll use some pseudocode here:

```
void paintTiles(Graphics g)
{
    for (Tile tile : allTiles)
    {
        g.drawImage(tile, player.x, player.y, null);
    }
}
```

The problem here is that **while** the painting thread is iterating over all tiles, the other thread may change the player coordinates. For example, some tiles may be painted with `player.x=10` and `player.y=20`, then the other thread changes the player coordinates, and thus the remaining tiles are painted with `player.x=15` and `player.y=25` - and you'll notice this as a "stripe" appearing between the tiles.

In the best case, this can be resolved rather easily:

```
void paintTiles(Graphics g)
{
    int currentPlayerX = player.x;
    int currentPlayerY = player.y;

    for (Tile tile : allTiles)
    {
        g.drawImage(tile, currentPlayerX, currentPlayerY, null);
    }
}
```

This way, the "current" player coordinates will remain the same while iterating over the tiles.

Comment: Thanks, I never realized that it would use different player coordinates from the other threads.  Would you suggest I keep my current threads or put them all together?

Comment: I can't give a recommendataion, not knowing the (intended) architecture of the game. "Usually", there's the rendering Thread (Event Dispatch Thread), and a single Game Thread, and I think that for a "simple" Tile Game, this should be sufficient. More threads tend to make things more complicated in terms of synchronization, and as long as there is no *really* time-consuming task to be performed, there's hardly a benefit of multiple threads that was worth the hassle, but ... all that without any knowledge about the game